# VueJS + Typescript + dynamic import

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs

I previously opened an issue here https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8801
It was wrong place :(

I use Vue CLI 3 with Typescript v3.4.3
When I run a test from CLI I got several issues

```
Jest give me a problem about import *

 import * as tslib_1 from "tslib";
           ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token *

      4 | import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
      5 | import {storeFactory} from '@/store';
    > 6 | import List from '@/core/workflow-builder/NodeBuilder.vue';
        | ^
      7 | import {WidgetStateMixin} from '@owui-commons/vue-widget-state-manager';
      8 | 
      9 | const localVue = createLocalVue();

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/unit/List.spec.ts:6:1)
```

I looking for files have import * as tslib_1 from "tslib"; in my node_modules, I find out there are some in rxjs/_esm5 folder

```
transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "node_modules/(?!rxjs/)"
  ],
```

Please feel free to check link on the top to see my jest configuration and previous log messages

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here the **solution**:

- install next `npm i --save next` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/next/)
- Create .babelrc file

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"]
}
```

it works for me without use @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import

**References:**

https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/5416#issuecomment-428674773

Comment: next.js is a full meta framework for react. Installing it just to fix some transpilation issue within a vue application seems, how we would say in German, like shooting with canons at sparrows - a quite extreme measure :)